# How to combine multiple variables in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, variables, instance-variables

I have `Sportists` with multiple disciplines and each discipline has one `record`. I'd like to display the record and in db they are saved as `m100rec`, `m200rec` and so on. Is there a way I could display them like so:

`@discipline + "rec"` ? I have saved `@discipline` in my `Controller` as an instance variable that contains the `session` value and that session has the discipline name saved in it.

**EDIT**

The view as it goes:

```
<% @sportists.each do |s| %>
 <%= s.m100rec %>
<% end %>
```

and since there are many disciplines which are all named by the same convention of 'discipline' + 'rec' I would like to make the code more readable and DRY and use just `<%= s.discipline+'rec' %>` somehow.

Comment: You want to display this data in the view?

Comment: You can display it just like you tried, with: `@discipline + 'rec'`.

Comment: @MarekLipka then I get this error:
`ActionView::Template::Error (/path/to/view.html.erb:137: syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting '('
...t_buffer.append=( s.@discipline + 'rec' );@output_buffer.saf...`

Comment: Just give an example, what do you have and what do you want.

Comment: @Xeen syntax error, it means you must have messed something up. I guess pasting `view.html.erb` content will help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: @MarekLipka Here you go: `<%= s.@discipline + 'rec' %>`

Comment: @Xeen Why you are doing `s.@discipline`? What is `s`? Post the full `code`

Comment: @Xeen `s.@discipline` call is illegal in Ruby. Did you learn any of Ruby basics?

Comment: @Xeen It might be `s.discipline`.Post your code.

Comment: It should probably be simply `<%= @discipline + 'rec' %>`, as according to OP `@discipline` is controller's instance variable. But I strongly advice learning Ruby basics.

Comment: @Xeen What is the `field name` of the record that has `m100rec` value?

Comment: @Pavan `m100rec` is the field name.

Comment: @Xeen Then you can use `<%= s.discipline.m100rec + "rec"%>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
<% @sportists.each do |s| %>
  <%= s.send("#{@discipline}rec") %>
<% end %>
```

Or

```
<% @sportists.each do |s| %>
  <%= s.attributes["#{@discipline}rec"] %>
<% end %>
```

- The first will work if `m100rec` is a field, method or association.
- The second will only work if `m100rec` is a field, but I think it's clearer what the code is doing.

---

A better way to structure the relation between `Sportists` and discipline records might be with a join table?

```
class Sportist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sportist_disciplines
  has_many :disciplines, :through => :sportist_disciplines
  ...
end

class SportistDiscipline < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sportist
  belongs_to :discipline
  ...
end

class Discipline < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sportist_disciplines
  has_many :sportists, :through => :sportist_disciplines
  ...
end
```

You could then have a field for `record` in the `sportist_disciplines` table, and look it up with -

In the controller:

```
@sportists = Sportist.includes(:sportist_disciplines).where( ... )
@discipline = Discipline.where( ... ).first
```

In the view:

```
 <% @sportists.each do |s| %>
   <%= s.sportist_disciplines.where(:discipline => @discipline).record %>
 <% end %>
```

N.B: This is only a suggestion for the 'rails-y' way to do this - it might not be suitable depending on the rest of the application and/or the source of the data.

Comment: `send` accepts a string, you can remove the `.to_sym`

Comment: @UriAgassi Good point! Edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
@discipline.map{|e| e + "rec"}
```

I think you are looking for something like this.

Comment: That gives me `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'map' for "m100":String):`

Comment: If you have only one discipline then you can just write  `@discipline + "rec"`